# GitHub page not load layout

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm very new in Jekyll and GitHub page.
Now I develop websites for my friend.
It's test local and looking great but when I publish to GitHub page,
some page not load layout. I'm not sure why.

my repo [GitHub](https://github.com/magnamm/bangkokimpress)|| [my site](https://magnamm.github.io/bangkokimpress)

EDIT TO CLARIFY QUESTION:

When generated on Github, the `.md` files in the `work` collection folder are not outputting with a layout.

The desired layout is `subpage`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Tell us the **specific** pages that do not load the layout and their source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your files in the `work` folder are not generating with a layout.

I note they all use the `subpage` layout.

I think the problem is they are not calling the layout properly.

I am not sure if `Jekyll` is case sensitive or not, but try renaming the file name of the layout from `Subpage.html` to lowercase `subpage.html`.